# Use Variable in Animationlistener

Tags: android, events, animation

How can i use a variable within an animationlistener

ex.

```
for(int i = 0; i<ids.length; i++) {

    //Doing some animation stuff based on
    //imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(ids[i]);




//I want to play a sound on the specific views animationstart           
    scalePause.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    sounds.play(letterSounds[i], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
}
```

});
}

Eclipse error: Cannot refer to a non final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method

(referring to i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
for(int i = 0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    ...
    ...
    //I want to play a sound on the specific views animationstart 
    final int index = i;      // assign to a final variable and use it.    
    scalePause.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    sounds.play(letterSounds[index ], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
}
```